# Change base layer on Gluon Maps

Tags: android, javafxports

I am developing an application with gluon maps and I would like to know if it is possible to change the base layer for a satellite layer similar to google maps. Thank you very much in advance.

Could it be changing the url of the host variable?

```
public class ImageRetriever {


    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(   ImageRetriever.class.getName() );

    static String host = "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/";
    static File cacheRoot;
    static boolean hasFileCache = false;
    static CacheThread cacheThread = null;
```

What would be the url of tiles from google maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base map is modified in the host variable by replacing the tile server with a valid XYZ tile server. Here is a list of tile server http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers.